# Is there a way to decrease margin with each child dynamically created so the children don't overflow parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

kinda weird title, but explains what I need. So I have a "hand" of cards, and they are dynamically pushed or popped. I have a negative left margin which makes the card look like they are on top of each other, but it becomes really clustered once there are too many cards. One choice is to make manual margins for every "hand" by number of cards, but I don't think that's practical. I searched the whole day for a solution, couldn't find one. Here's the example:

```
<div> 
    <img src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
</div>
```

```
div{
    width:100%;
    display:inline-flex;
}
img{
    height: 200px;
}
.rest{
    margin-left: -70px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/justdx/pen/rNVbEMp

What I basically need is dynamically smaller margin so cards look more stacked, without changing image size. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Not in the traditional sense, no you can not do this with pure `CSS` alone but...

You could use a `CSS Preprocessor`. [SASS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/css-preprocessor-sass/). Combining these two resources ([1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/if-else-condition-in-css/) & [2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/if-else-condition-in-css/)) you could use SASS to fulfil this requirement but it would be far easier to do it with the use of `JavaScript`/`JQuery`.

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        div{
            width:100%;
            display:inline-flex;
        }
        img{
            height: 200px;
        }
        .rest{
            margin-left: -70px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>

        function getWidth() {
          return Math.max(
            document.body.scrollWidth,
            document.documentElement.scrollWidth,
            document.body.offsetWidth,
            document.documentElement.offsetWidth,
            document.documentElement.clientWidth
          );
        }
        function repositionCards(){
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var numCards = $("#cards > img").length;
                var viewportWidth = getWidth();
                var margin = 95000/viewportWidth;
                if(margin > 125){
                    margin = 125;
                }
                $(".rest").css("margin-left", "-"+margin+"px");
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var numCards = $("#cards > img").length;
            var viewportWidth = getWidth();
            var margin = 95000/viewportWidth;
            if(margin > 125){
                margin = 125;
            }
            $(".rest").css("margin-left", "-"+margin+"px");
        });
        window.onresize = repositionCards;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cards"> 
    <img src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above snippet shows a `scaling` **margin** based on the `numCards`, the more cards, the closer they are grouped. You can adjust/find a *more-proper* formula that fits your requirement(s) but this scales sufficiently for a deck of cards.

Comment: I had a similar idea, but the catch is that i need to make this responsive, so any screen gets the same result. You got any idea how I can do it?

Comment: @Sh.z answer updated, if you now re-size your browser it will respond accordingly, you can play with the boundaries as you see fit to account for min/max spacing in the `if`

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS can't use the number of element to count it's own margin or other css attribute. You can probably use JS or something like that:

```
.rest {
    margin-left: -70px;
}
.rest:nth-child(n+8) {
  margin-left:-90px;
}
.rest:nth-child(n+12) {
  margin-left:-120px;
}
```

Or you can use Flexbox to fill the whole width, if you have such aim.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of how it can be done in js

```js
const container = document.querySelectorAll('.cards')[0];
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.cards img');

const totalCards = cards.length;
const cardWidth = cards[0].offsetWidth;
const containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
const margin = (containerWidth - cardWidth) / totalCards - 1;

console.log(margin, containerWidth)
cards.forEach((card, index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      return
    }
    card.style.marginLeft = `${-(cardWidth - margin)}px`;
})
```

```css
.cards {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.cards img {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards"> 
    <img src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
      <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
      <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
      <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
      <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
  
</div>
```

Comment: This gives weird results. Maybe I wasn't clear on my question. I want the cards to fill the div, but not overflow it. With that I implied that the cards should have the same space within each other. Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS solution: Set the right margin of each card to negative the width of the card, making the card effectively take no width from the flex box. Then use justify-content:space-between to spread the cards evenly and let the visible overflow place the cards one on top of the other.

```css
img{
  width: 90px;
  margin-right: -90px;
}
div {
  display:flex;
  width:calc(100% - 90px);
  margin-bottom:10px;
  justify-content:space-between
}
```

```html
<div> 
    <img src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
</div>
<div> 
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
</div>
<div> 
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
    <img class="rest" src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: This worked fine, but the second I switched to percentages it would overflow it and wouldn't change. Do you think there is something we can do about that?

Comment: @Sh.z - For me percentages almost work, but the width calculation needs tweaking to account for the circular dependency. If you can you post a codepen to show what you're doing with percentages then I'll see if I can revise my answer appropriately.

Comment: https://codepen.io/justdx/pen/rNVbEMp , I tried different values but whenever an image is added it doesn't change the margin, it only adds images that eventually overflow the div